# How do I access environment variables in Travis CI

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, travis-ci, chai

I have built a site using SQL Server and Node.js and I use Mocha and Chai for my tests. It all works fine locally, and any tests that don't require accessing the database run correctly on Travis CI, but because I have my password, username, db path, etc. stored in my .env file, which is gitignored Travis can't access the DB for testing.

I tried to set the environment variables according to [these instructions from the Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings), but the log in fails. I know that the environment variables are being found, because the error message is: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Login failed for user 'EventAdmin'.` and 'EventAdmin' is the username from the environment variables, but for some reason the password isn't being accepted. I know that the password is right, because I copied it straight from my .env file.

My .travis.yml file looks like this:

```js
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "4.1"
  - "4.0"
  - "0.12"
  - "0.11"
  - "0.10"
  - "iojs"
before_install:
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
script: grunt test
```

My test (which works locally) looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var assert = chai.assert;
var chaihttp = require('chai-http');


chai.use(chaihttp);

require('../server.js');

describe('Test /showfullteam route', function() {
  it('should load all MS contacts from /showfullteam', function(done) {
    chai.request('localhost:3000')
      .get('/showfullteam')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(err).to.eql(null);
        for (var i = 0; i < res.body.length; i++) {
          expect(res.body[i]).to.include.keys('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'newsletterSubscription', 'contactDescription', 'msTeamMember', 'msTeamTitle', 'showOnHomePage', 'headShot', 'company', 'address', 'country', 'interestId', 'allowNotifications', 'allowPersonalInfoSharing');
          expect(res.body[i].msTeamMember).to.eql(true);
          expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].lastName).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].email).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          if (res.body[i].newsletterSubscription) {
            assert.typeOf(res.body[i].newsletterSubscription, 'boolean');
          }
          if (res.body[i].msTeamMember) {
            assert.typeOf(res.body[i].msTeamMember, 'boolean');
          }
          if (res.body[i].showOnHomePage) {
            assert.typeOf(res.body[i].showOnHomePage, 'boolean');
          }
          if (res.body[i].allowNotifications) {
            assert.typeOf(res.body[i].allowNotifications, 'boolean');
          }
          if (res.body[i].interestId) {
            assert.isNumber(res.body[i].interestId);
          }
          expect(typeof res.body[i].contactDescription).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].headShot).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].company).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].address).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].country).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
          expect(typeof res.body[i].allowPersonalInfoSharing).to.be.a('string') || expect(typeof res.body[i].firstName).to.be.a('null');
        };
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

You can see the full project on my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mrbgit/event-site/tree/working-branch) and the failing tests on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/mrbgit/event-site/jobs/103506907)

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to set the environment variables, but that wasn't the problem. The issue was that SQL Server is not compatible with travis. I switched to [mariadb](https://mariadb.org/) and the tests pass :-)

Comment: "I figured out how to set the environment variables". Please add this info here...